# Error at "unsigned" when creating table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I can't tell what is wrong with this query.

```
create table roles
(
  id                int unsigned        not null   auto_increment
 ,name              varchar(32)         not null
 ,phone             varchar(256)        not null

 ,primary key   (id)
)
engine=innodb
default charset=utf8;
```

When I try to run it, I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'unsigned  not null    auto_increment ,role_id int unsigned ' at
>   line 3

Using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but this schema works for me in MySQL 5.7. Is it possible there's some invisible character in there causing trouble?

Comment: works fine for me as well. where are you running this?

Comment: With respect, you did *not* get that error message from the table you showed us. You got it from some other table, one containing a column `role_id`.

Comment: got catch @O.Jones but it's actually `role_id`

Comment: @tadman Thanks. I had carried a lot of tables over from another file, and they came with some unwanted formatting.

Comment: @O. Jones You're correct. That was the error I was getting on another table with the identical problem. I went ahead and answered the question with my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the advice, tadman

Turns out I had a tab between "int unsigned" instead of a space. Replaced the tab with a space and it worked just fine.

That was driving me crazy for almost 2 hours.

Comment: AFAIK, TAB and Space are treated equally by MySQL. There must have been something else there.

Comment: @Barmar There could have been an invisible character that Notepad++ wasn't seeing I suppose. Whatever it was, replacing the space between them with a real space did the trick.

Comment: Some editors are very bad at showing invisible characters, others have a mode that sheds light on them. One trick is to use the arrow keys to "step over" the characters in question. Sometimes tapping right doesn't move the cursor visibly, that usually means there's a zero-width invisible character at that spot that needs to be deleted. You can also dump your text into a [hex editor](https://hexed.it) and have a look at the bytes.